# How to compare different logarithm functions with same base?

Tags: algorithms

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sIAF.png)

When I take logarithms of all of these functions, I get this:

$n \log_2 10$

$1/3 *\log_2 n$

$n \log_2 n$

$\log_2 \log_2 n$

$(\log_2 n)^{1/2}$

Now I need to compare them, how do I compare them analytically? Do I take values of them, for example $n=100$ and compare them? Is it safe?

Comment: It may be useful to look at the derivative of these functions with respect to $n$. All are monotone increasing but which ones grow faster?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: What do you mean by "compare"? What exactly are you trying to decide?

Comment: I'm trying to sort them on the basis of which is taking more time and which is taking less time.

Comment: [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Orders_of_common_functions) may help

Comment: umm it does help. :)